# Leaving jQuery, wrote a simple ajax function, but chained methods will not wait

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

Update: Added a simpler demonstration jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/47sfj3Lv/3/.

reproducing the problem in much less code I'm trying to move away from jQuery.

Some of my code, for populating some tables, has code like this

```
var hb = new hbLister(url: '#attributes.listURL#')
  .getData(#url.page#, #url.per#)
  .search(searchColumn, searchParam)
  .render();
```

- `hbLister` would initialize some things
- `getData` would perform an $.ajax call
- `search` would`console.log('filtering data')` and apply the search conditions against a javascript object
- `render` would put the results on the page.

Importantly, `search` wouldn't fire until after the ajax call in `getData` finished.

So, now I have this ajax constructor. I've abbreviated as much of this code as I can.

```
let ajax = function (options, hooks, headers) {
  let that = this;

  // enforce parameter types
  // copy parameters to this.base
  this.base = { options: options, hooks: hooks, headers: headers }

  return function (url, options, data, hooks, headers) {
    // enforce variable types
    // merge options and hooks with their base.counterparts

    headers = new Headers(Object.assign({}, that.base.headers, headers));
    options.headers = headers;

    return fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json().then(json => {
          console.log('processing');
          if (response.ok) {
            // it's omitted here but the Base functions are defined
            // in the constructor parameters
            hooks.successBase(json, response.status, response.headers);
            hooks.success(response.json, response.status, response.headers)
          } else {
            hooks.failureBase(json, response.status, response.headers);
            hooks.failure(response.json, response.status, response.headers)
          }
        })
      });
  }
}
```

The idea is that I can say

```
let tableLister = new ajax()
```

And then`getData` can call

```
tableLister = tableLister(hb.url, // url
  { type: "GET" }, // options
  config.data, // data
  { success: successFn } // hooks, success being the callback
)
```

The jQuery call would properly give me and then `processing` and then `filtering data`.

This function gives me `filtering data`, an error, and then`processing`, because I cannot seem to get the chain(`.search(...).render()`) to wait til the ajax call is done.

Here's a self-contained example on jsFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/47sfj3Lv/3/

I am sure the answer is in async and await, but I have not been able to get it to work.

Here is an example of what I've tried

```
  return await (async function () {
    console.log('fetching')
    let fetcher = await fetch(url, options);

    console.log('getting json');
    return await fetcher.json().then((json) => {
      console.log('have json, doing hooks');
      if (fetcher.ok) {
        let argXHR = { json: json}
        hooks.successBase(argXHR, hooks.params);
        hooks.success.forEach(v => v(argXHR, hooks.params));
        hooks.afterSend(argXHR, hooks.params);
      } else {
        let argXHR = { json: json,}
        hooks.failureBase(argXHR, hooks.params);
        hooks.failure.forEach(v => v(argXHR, hooks.params));
        hooks.afterError(argXHR, hooks.params);
      }
      console.log('finished hooks')
    })
  }())
```

And no matter what I do, the chain, continues before this await finishes..

---

I got code with XMLHttpRequest to work. The method chain (`.getData().search(...).render()`) works with this, because this doesn't allow the ajax function to return before the request is finished and callbacks are executed. **I'd still prefer to make `.fetch()` work.

```
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

  let urlParams = [];
  Object.keys(data).forEach((v) => urlParams.push(v + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[v])));
  urlParams = urlParams.join('&')

  xhr.open(options.method, options.url, false);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(state) {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      let json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      hooks.successBase(json, xhr.status, xhr.getResponseHeader);
      hooks.success.forEach(v => v(json, xhr.status, xhr.getResponseHeader));
    }
  }
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    let json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    hooks.failureBase(json, xhr.status, xhr.getResponseHeader);
    hooks.failure.forEach(v => v(json, xhr.status, xhr.getResponseHeader));
  }
  for (h in headers) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(h, headers[h])
  }
  xhr.send(urlParams)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was difficult for me to understand, so I wanted to share if anyone else has the same issue.

It seems that an async method will break a method chain, there's no way around that. And since fetch is asynchronous, await must be used, and in order for await to be used, the calling method must be declared async. Thus the method chain will be broken.

The way the method chain is called must be changed.

In my OP, I linked https://jsfiddle.net/47sfj3Lv/3/ as a much simpler version of the same problem. StackOverflow's 'fiddle' effectively blocks 'fetch' for security reasons, so I need to use JSFiddle for demonstration.

[Here's a working version](https://jsfiddle.net/j4fr29hs/) of the same code using `then` and how/why it works, and a [slightly shorter version](https://jsfiddle.net/j4fr29hs/1/), because await can be specified with the the fetch, obviously.

```
let obj = {};

// methods with fetch ideally should be specified async.
// async calls will automatically return a promise
obj.start = async () => {
  console.log('start begins')
  let retText = "",
    fetcher = fetch('/', {}).then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      console.log('fetch\'s last then')
      retText = text
    })
  // fetcher has just been declared. It hasn't done anything yet.
  console.log('fetch requested, returned length:', retText.length)

  // this makes the fetcher and sequential then's happen
  await fetcher;
  console.log('await let fetch finish, returned length:', retText.length)

  // Async functions will return a promise, but the return specified here
  // will be passed to the next 'then'
  return obj
}
obj.middle = () => {
  console.log('middle called')
  // Because this is not declared async, it behaves normally
  return obj;
}
obj.end = () => {
  console.log('end called')
  // Because this is not declared async, it behaves normally
}

console.log('Method 1: ', obj.start()
  // Because start is Async, it returns obj wrapped in a promise.
  // As with any function, step may be named Anything you like
  .then((step) => step.middle())
  // Middle is not Async, but since it's wrapped in then
  // it returns a promise
  .then((step) => step.end())
)

// This is just wrapped in a timer so the two logs don't intermix with each other

// This is definitely the preferred method. Non-async chain-methods that return 
// a reference to their object, do not need to wrapped in then().
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('------------------------')
  console.log('Method 2: ', obj.start()
    // Because start is Async, it returns obj wrapped in a promise.
    // As with any function, step may be named Anything you like
    .then((step) => step.middle().end())
  )
}, 3000)
```